# Show that $\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}},\cdots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, radicals, nested-radicals

Show that $$\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}, \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}},\cdots$$
is increasing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Simply from $ a_{n+1}^2 - a_{n}^2 > 0} $

Comment: $\sqrt (2+x) $ is always greater than $\sqrt (2)$ where x is greater than zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $a_n = \sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}$. Inductive step: $$a_n> a_{n-1} \implies 2+a_n > 2+ a_{n-1} \implies \sqrt{2+a_n} > \sqrt{2 + a_{n-1}} \implies a_{n+1} > a_n$$

We were allowed to take the square root because clearly $a_n>0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The function $\sqrt{x}$  is increasing